# FullSimplify Nested radicals

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to simplify this expression with Mathematica.

$\sqrt{2-a^2-2\sqrt{1-a^2}}, 0<a<1$

It can be simplified as

$\sqrt{1+1-a^2-2\sqrt{1-a^2}}=\sqrt{(1-\sqrt{1-a^2})^2}=1-\sqrt{1-a^2}$

denesting original radical.
I used the command

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[2 - a^2 - 2 Sqrt[1 - a^2]], 0 < a < 1]
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[2 - a^2 - 2 Sqrt[1 - a^2]] /. a^2 -> 1 - x] /. 
 x -> 1 - a^2

(*  Sqrt[(-1 + Sqrt[1 - a^2])^2]   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Include assumption `Simplify[Sqrt[2 - a^2 - 2 Sqrt[1 - a^2]] /. a^2 -> 1 - x, 
  0 < x < 1] /. x -> 1 - a^2`

Answer (score 3):

```
Reduce[Reduce[y == Sqrt[2 - a^2 - 2 Sqrt[1 - a^2]] && 0 < a < 1, a, Reals], y, Reals]
```

or

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[2 - a^2 - 2 Sqrt[1 - a^2]], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Reduce[Reduce[y == # && 0 < a < 1, a, Reals], y, Reals] &}]
```

> 0 < a < 1 && y == 1 - Sqrt[1 - a^2]

```
Sqrt[2-a^2-2 Sqrt[1-a^2]] /. Sqrt[a_ + b : k_. Sqrt[x_]]:>
  Sqrt[(a+Sqrt[a^2-b^2])/2]+Sign[k] Sqrt[(a-Sqrt[a^2-b^2])/2] // Simplify[#,0<a<1]&
```

> 1 - Sqrt[1 - a^2]