# How do I suppress an automatic sign change? II

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, conversion

Let me be try to be highly specific, as my previous attempt [How do I suppress an automatic sign change?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230543/how-do-i-suppress-an-automatic-sign-change) to pose the question initially had a sign error, and perhaps became a little muddled.

---

---

In the course of pursuing the question [Evaluate a certain three-dimensional constrained integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral), the term (one of 694)

```
r = (202338335476512488921084723200 x^6 Sqrt[-(-1 + 2 x) (2 - x +  2 Sqrt[1 - x - 2 x^2])]Boole[1/38 (10 - Sqrt[5]) < x <= 1/4])/(319794090309 (723 + 17 Sqrt[5]))
```

is generated.

My attempt, r/.c, to apply (so the term becomes integrable--as can be checked) the rule (now corrected from earlier version--again, my apologies)

```
c := Sqrt[-(-1 + 2 x) (2 - x + 2 Sqrt[1 - x - 2 x^2])] -> 1 - 2 x + Sqrt[1 - x - 2 x^2]
```

fails (because apparently the expression -(-1 + 2 x) is ab initio converted to (1-2 x)).

What needs to be done, so that the intended conversion takes place?

Unfortunately, it would seem the apparent "automatic" conversion of  $-(-1 + 2 x)$  to $(1-2 x)$ is not so "automatic" that it is performed in the formula for $r$ itself, which would obviate the apparent dilemma.

Comment: Probably I do not understand something. When I evaluated your expression for r the term `-(-1 + 2 x)` automatically transformed into `(1 - 2 x)`. Did it happen with your expression also? If yes, the rule application is senseless. If not, there is something wrong with your code. May it be that a part of your expression was held?

Comment: Thanks--Alexei Boulbitch. So, the question appears to remain of how can I accomplish the clearly intended conversion (one I need to do repeatedly), so I obtain integrable terms.

Comment: For me, the automatic conversion of −(−1+2) to (1−2) is performed in the formula for  itself (V12.1.1). In any case, the situation you describe should be handled by `HoldPattern`: `c = HoldPattern[Sqrt[-(-1 + 2 x) (2 - x + 2 Sqrt[1 - x - 2 x^2])]] -> 
 Sqrt[(1 - 2 x) (2 - x + 2 Sqrt[1 - x - 2 x^2])]`.  However, I can't test it, since `r` is automatically converted.

Comment: Fabulous--Michael E2! It now works--in my V. 12.1.0.0  .

Comment: Unbelieveably frustrating! I have this array of 694 terms, call it H. If I use the command H/.c, where c is as indicated. The change does NOT now take place. Also, Do[H[[i]]=H[[i]]/.c,{i,1,694}] does not work either. Incredible! Seems to be totally unpredictable.

Comment: Could something be amiss with my particular version V. 12.1.0.0. Need to reinstall?

Comment: When I evaluate `c` it becomes `lhs -> rhs` where `lhs` and `rhs` are identical. So it is not surprising that applying this rule does nothing.

Comment: Thanks--Carl Woll! I was beginning to think I was losing my mind (which I still may be doing). So, is my question/problem still open/unresolved? So, does the approach/comment of Michael E2 need to be elaborated upon or somehow adjusted?

Comment: I think an example of where the replacement rule is needed (actually makes something integrable that wasn't) would be useful. I don't think using this kind of replacement rule is a good approach because it relies on having the FullForm of the lhs of the rule matching the FullForm of a part of the expression to be replaced. If you have an example where the rule helps, I suspect an alternate, more robust approach could be suggested.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer your question, but hopefully provides an alternate approach where you don't need to worry about pattern matching issues when doing replacements. The following function (inspired by chyanog's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188487/45431) to a related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/186778/45431)) is a more programmatic way to denest some radical expressions:

```
denestSqrt[e_, domain_, x_] := Replace[
    y /. Solve[Simplify[Reduce[Reduce[y == e && domain, x], y, Reals], domain], y],
    {
    {r_} :> r,
    _ -> e
    }
]
```

Now, instead of doing the following (and worrying about possible issues with pattern matching due to small differences in the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm)):

```
r /. c
```

you can do:

```
r /. Sqrt[s_] :> denestSqrt[Sqrt[s], 1/38 (10 - Sqrt[5]) < x <= 1/4, x]
```

> (202338335476512488921084723200 x^6 (1 - 2 x + Sqrt[1 - x - 2 x^2]) Boole[
> 1/38 (10 - Sqrt[5]) < x <= 1/4])/(319794090309 (723 + 17 Sqrt[5]))

Comment: OK, very interesting! I have an array of length 694, with different Boole statements and various integrands--some of the form in the question--for which I've already developed various denesting rules. (Not all the integrands need to be denested.) So, can I systematically proceed through the array, denesting as I go, applying the approach you indicate?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work--no detesting.  r = (202338335476512488921084723200 x^6 Sqrt[-(-1 + 2 x) (2 - x + 
       2 Sqrt[1 - x - 2 x^2])]
     Boole[1/38 (10 - Sqrt[5]) < x <= 1/4])/(319794090309 (723 + 
      17 Sqrt[5])); r /. 
 Sqrt[s_] :> denestSqrt[Sqrt[s], Last[r][[1]], x] yielding (202338335476512488921084723200 x^6 Sqrt[(1 - 2 x) (2 - x + 
      2 Sqrt[1 - x - 2 x^2])]
    Boole[1/38 (10 - Sqrt[5]) < x <= 1/4])/(319794090309 (723 + 
     17 Sqrt[5]))  Trying to generalize for array members, where r= G[[679]]..

Comment: @PaulB.Slater See update. You will need to use strict inequalities, though.

Comment: Got it to work, apparently! But now how do I, in general (for my 694-long array), render non-strict inequalities into purely strict form, so the methodology can work?

Comment: @PaulB.Slater I think it should work with nonstrict inequalities now.

Comment: Thanks once again! Will try!

Comment: How do I extract the Boole component of an expression?

Comment: If I use r=-((970157260800 Sqrt[-x^11 (-1 + 2 x)]
   Boole[1/6 < x < 1/38 (10 - Sqrt[5])])/(723 + 17 Sqrt[5])), for example, I get Simplify::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity -10+Sqrt[5]+38 Root[{276664364883270125-5036922425 Power[<<2>>]+Slot[<<1>>]^4&,625 Power[<<2>>]-2266434477123748864 Power[<<2>>]+4532868954247497728 Power[<<2>>]&},{3,1}] is equal to zero. Assuming it is. Should I just ignore such messages--they, off-hand, seem harmless, as the original expression appears to remain unchanged.

Comment: Carl Woll: I'm applying the denestSqrt function to Sqrt[9 + 96 z^2 + 12 Sqrt[-1 + 16 z - 32 z^2] - 48 z (1 + Sqrt[-1 + 16 z - 32 z^2])] and getting Root[225 - 4320 z + 29376 z^2 - 82944 z^3 + 
   82944 z^4 + (-18 + 96 z - 192 z^2) #1^2 + #1^4 &, 4], so it doesn't seem to be "detesting"????

Comment: "denesting" not "detesting" in previous comment--***spell-checker!