# Simplifying expressions with nested square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, pattern-matching, assumptions

When I run

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2])^2], {1 > 2 x^2 y^2 > 0}]
```

I obtain `1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]`. However, when I run

```
FullSimplify[ExpandAll[Sqrt[(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2])^2]], {1 > 2 x^2 y^2 > 0}]
```

I am never able to recover the simpler expression and I always obtain `Sqrt[2 - 2 x^2 y^2 - 2 Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]]`. (I did try various `PowerExpand` and `ComplexityFunction` variants with no avail.)

***How to deal with this? Is there a way to ask `FullSimplify` to look into square roots and search for squares of simpler expressions that have unambiguous square roots given the assumptions?***

---

Ultimately, I believe that the issue is with FullSimplify not realizing that some forms of the expressions would simplify even further in the next step *given the assumptions*.

Here is a more advanced example of what I am dealing with and that I would like to simplify more algorithmically. First:

```
FullSimplify[
  -Sqrt[2] x^2 y 
  + Sqrt[1 - x^2 y^2 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]]/y 
  + x Sqrt[
       ((-1 + 2 x^2 y^2) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]))/(1 + Sqrt[1- 2 x^2 y^2])
  ], 
{1 > 2 x^2 y^2 > 0, x > 0, y > 0}]
```

returns the same expression. However, one can see by "manual" operations that

```
Simplify[
 Simplify[
  Simplify[
    -Sqrt[2] x^2 y 
    + Sqrt[1 - x^2 y^2 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]]/y 
    + x Sqrt[
         ((-1 + 2 x^2 y^2) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]))/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2])
    ], 
  {1 > 2 x^2 y^2 > 0, x > 0, y > 0}] 
 /. {1 - x^2 y^2 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2] -> (1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2])^2/2},
 {1 > 2 x^2 y^2 > 0, x > 0, y > 0}] 
/. {((-1 + 2 x^2 y^2) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]))/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]) -> ((1 - 2 x^2 y^2) 2 x^2 y^2)/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2])^2},
{1 > 2 x^2 y^2 > 0, x > 0, y > 0}]
```

the expression is actually identically zero given the assumptions. Note that no further assumptions were used in these "manual" operations, only identities that apply under the assumptions `{1 > 2 x^2 y^2 > 0, x > 0, y > 0}` were used. Ideally the solution should work also in this example.

Comment: This answer in this link might be helpful:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230686/how-do-i-suppress-an-automatic-sign-change-ii.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As kindly pointed out by JimB in the comments, it turns out that the function I needed was given by Carl Woll in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230700/46818):

```
denestSqrt[e_, domain_, X] := 
  Replace[
    z /. Solve[
      Simplify[Reduce[Reduce[
        z == e && domain, X
      ], z, Reals], domain], z], 
  {{r_} :> r, _ -> e}];
```

This function is used as follows

```
nasty /. Sqrt[s_] :> denestSqrt[Sqrt[s], mydomain, myvar]]
```

It takes the `nasty` expression, finds every square root, and looks whether it can be reduced given that the variable `myvar` fulfills the conditions specified in `mydomain`.

---

Let us see how it fares with the advanced example. I have more than one variable, `x,y`. In principle one can use more than one variable by `myvar = {x,y}` and specify the conditions in `mydomain = x>0 && y>0 && 1>2 x^2 y^2>0`. This did not yield satisfactory results. However, I was able to choose a different variable $X = \sqrt{2}xy$ so that all the square roots end up only referring to $X$ and not $y$:

```
nasty = FullSimplify[
  -Sqrt[2] x^2 y 
  + Sqrt[1 - x^2 y^2 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]]/y 
  + x Sqrt[((-1 + 2 x^2 y^2) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]))/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2])] 
  /. {x -> X/(y Sqrt[2])}, 
  {y > 0, 1 > X > 0}
]
```

Then I was able to finally obtain

```
Simplify[nasty /. Sqrt[s_] :> denestSqrt[Sqrt[s], 0 < X < 1, X]]
>> 0
```

So far, this has also worked for any other expression that I get in my expansions.

Answer (score 3):

Eliminate the term you want to ged rid of with Solve

```
f = Sqrt[(1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2])^2];

fe = ExpandAll[f];

fsol /. First@
   Solve[{fe == fsol, g == Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2], g >= 0}, fsol, {g}, 
    Reals] // FullSimplify[#, 1 > 2 x^2 y^2 > 0] &

(*   1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 x^2 y^2]   *)
```